# Content-Security-Policy not working on node js app at host server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-modules

```html
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const csp = require('helmet-csp');


app.use(csp({
    directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'"],
    }
}));

app.get('/api/version', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello everybody');
});


app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I try to add the CSP this's working on my Localhost but when I public on the Host Server they return this

Refused to load the font '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried for this today to find a method to work for me please help [error on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKppq.png) [work on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvea4.png)